# Ask a question on Helmert matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{align}
H=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\cdots&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&0&\cdots&0&0
\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&-\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}&0&\cdots&0&0
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots
\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\cdots&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&\frac{-(n-1)}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

In my professor's lecture notes, it said $H=I-2A$, where A is an idempotent matrix. Then we can show H is orthogonal matrix. But I search online, I didn't see anyone else said H can be expressed as I-2A.

Comment: The big matrix should be denoted as $H$ instead of $P$ .

Comment: @Haon Correct. Changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's show that it's sadly false for $n = 3$ : $H := \pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & - \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}}$.

We want to show that $A := \frac{I_3 - H}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\pmatrix{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0\\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & 1+ \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}}$ is not idempotent, *i.e.*: $A^2 \neq A$.

It suffices to check the first coefficient of $A^2$:
$$(A^2)_{1,1} = \frac{1}{4}\Bigg(\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)^2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}\sqrt{3}}\Bigg) = \frac{1}{4}\Bigg(1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)\Bigg)$$
Checking the difference with the first coefficient of $A$ gives:
$$(A^2)_{1,1} - A_{1,1} = \frac{1}{4}\Bigg(1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)\Bigg) - \frac{1}{2}\Bigg(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\Bigg) \approx -0.0057 \neq 0$$
A small difference but still a non-zero one unfortunately.
The reason I had to go to $n = 3$ is because $n = 2$ should work based on my calculations.

${}$

However, $H$ is still orthogonal for all $n \geq 2$, your professor was right on that point. Let $D := HH^T$. Let's check case by case on the coefficients $D_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} H_{i,k}H_{j,k}$ :

- $i = j = 1$: $$D_{1,1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (H_{1,k})^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(\sqrt{n})^2} = n \times \frac{1}{n} = 1$$
- $i = j \neq 1$: $$\begin{split} D_{i,i} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (H_{i,k})^2
  &= \Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} \frac{1}{\big(\sqrt{i(i-1)}\big)^2}\Bigg) \,\,+\,\, \frac{(i-1)^2}{\big(\sqrt{i(i-1)}\big)^2}\\
  &= \Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} \frac{1}{i(i-1)}\Bigg) \,\,+\,\, \frac{i-1}{i}\\
  &= (i-1)\frac{1}{i(i-1)} + \frac{i-1}{i} = \frac{1}{i} + \frac{i-1}{i} = 1 \end{split}$$
- $i = 1 \neq j$ (by symmetry we'll aslo have the case $j = 1 \neq i$): $$\begin{split} D_{1,j} = D_{j,1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} H_{1,k}H_{j,k}
  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{j-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j(j-1)}}\Bigg) \,\,-\,\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{j-1}{\sqrt{j(j-1)}}\\
  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{j-1}{\sqrt{j(j-1)}} \,-\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{j-1}{\sqrt{j(j-1)}} = 0 \end{split}$$
- $i < j$, $i \neq 1$, $j \neq 1$ (by symmetry we'll also have the case $i > j$):
  $$\begin{split} D_{i,j} = D_{j,i} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} H_{i,k}H_{j,k}\\
  &= \Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i(i-1)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j(j-1)}}\Bigg) \,\,-\,\, \frac{i-1}{\sqrt{i(i-1)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j(j-1)}}\\
  &= \frac{i-1}{\sqrt{i(i-1)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j(j-1)}} \,-\, \frac{i-1}{\sqrt{i(i-1)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j(j-1)}} = 0\end{split}$$

After all this, we obtain: $D = HH^T = I_n$, and $H$ is indeed orthogonal.